# Sort a list on picker selection

Tags: xamarin.forms

My application is made in Xmaman forms
I need a picker with selection based on my data in the list picker should show years if data have between 2018 to 2023 it should show picker selection 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 and 2013

For example
If data is from 2018 to 2023 so picker should create years 210 2019 2020 2021 2023

Comment: Can you tell us about the specific type of data you have?

Comment: Whats you question is, how to get the picker values sorted or how to select range of years in the custom list?

Answer (score 1):

there are many different ways to do this in C#

```
var years = Enumerable.Range(start,end);
foreach(var x in years)
  MyPicker.Items.Add(x);
```